# What are the options for digital magazine publishing?

Tags: adobe-indesign, marketing, digital, publishing

I work for a company and we produce a 60 page magazine. We do a print version but are trying to figure out the best, most cost-effective way to create and publish a digital version. Also keeping in mind that our reader is not generally tech savvy but we are potentially interested in the analytics aspect for marketing purposes.

Ideally we would like to host/embed it on our own site and not pay a subscription fee. These are the options I have looked at so far:

Adobe DPS:
To my understanding Adobe DPS digital documents only work in the Adobe Content Viewer app. Is that correct? The pricing is not clear on the Adobe DPS for Enterprise site and I had read/heard conflicting things from their phone sales and website about whether its included in the full Creative Cloud subscription price. To my understanding this suite functions within InDesign but I am also unclear on that and if this would be a good option.

flippingbook, issuu, emagcreator, etc:
The problem with most of these sites is the way in which the content embeds into the page and using custom domains etc. Also the business subscriptions tend to be high and we are on a pretty tight budget as a not for profit. Some also do not let you upload InDesign/PDFs but you instead need to create the magazine with their online app. I would love to know if anyone has used any that work better than others.

App:
Another option I have read about is creating your own app for the magazine. We do not have a developer onsite but could look into this if someone has experience I would love to hear if it was worth the investment.

Thanks for any help! Would also love to see some published examples if you know of any.

EDIT: The magazine has 5 different versions. The first and last 8 pages are customizable to the organization they are for and the well content is all the same. It is a member magazine that each organization provides to its members. All the members are in different geographic areas. Each organization has their own way of sharing it some through an enewsletter link to their website and some upload it to their member CRM system for members to access. We want to keep the same look and feel as the print version but maybe with some added on interactivity.

Comment: Hi user3299565, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Can you add what your main criteria are? For example, do people pay per issue, pay for a subscription, or is it free/ad supported? Are you looking to recreate the look and feel of the print magazine, or simply put the content online?

Comment: I updated my question to include those answers. I am really considering Adobe DPS but I don't know many people who have used it or can give me some good feedback on it and how easy it is for users to move over. I didn't even have Adobe Content Viewer on my phone until the other day.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at FlexPaper;

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

- No lock in subscriptions, you decide where you host your content
- Super sharp text zoom quality
- One time fees available
- Publications accessible to screen readers